# Image.open can't handle random selected image-variable Python

Tags: python, variables, random, tkinter, python-imaging-library

This is my first Python-script/program so I have googled everything and starting to get the grip a little.

I am trying to make a program that randomly picks a picture in a directory and display it as a label.

Everything goes well except one thing. I have made the random picture as a variable and try to tell Image.open to use the path in the variable. Thing is that Image.open does not recognise the variable as a filename/path but instead it recognize it as

```
"PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=P size=980x93 at 0xF185A8".
```

I have googled all night but cant find an answer or solution to this. If I print both `img1-variable` and `path1-variable` it comes out right.

Anyone have a clue how to solve this? I would be very grateful for any answers! 
I have Python 2.7.3

And this is my script (not finished).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

root = Tkinter.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" %(w, h))
root.configure(background="darkgreen")
dir = 'decks/'
img1 = random.choice(os.listdir(dir))
path1 = dir+img1
card1 = Image.open(path1)
card1 = card1.resize((140, 190), Image.ANTIALIAS)
magicback = Image.open("datapics/magicback.jpg")
magicback = magicback.resize((140, 190), Image.ANTIALIAS)
magicbutton = ImageTk.PhotoImage(magicback)
label = Label(root, image=magicbutton)
label.image = magicbutton
label.place(x=1, y=20)
label1 = Label(root, image=card1)
label1.image = card1
label1.place(x=1, y=230)
label2 = Label(root, image=magicbutton)
label2.image = magicbutton
label2.place(x=151, y =230)
label3 = Label(root, image=magicbutton)
label3.image = magicbutton
label3.place(x=301, y=230)
label4 = Label(root, image=magicbutton)
label4.image = magicbutton
label4.place(x=451, y=230)
label5 = Label(root, image=magicbutton)
label5.image = magicbutton
label5.place(x=601, y=230)
label6 = Label(root, image=magicbutton)
label6.image = magicbutton
label6.place(x=751, y=230)
label7 = Label(root, image=magicbutton)
label7.image = magicbutton
label7.place(x=901, y=230)
root.mainloop(0)
```

Comment: "Image.open does not recognise the variable" Prove it.

Comment: Also, you can probably delete most of your code after `label1.*` for the purposes of asking a question (a la [ssccse](http://sscce.org/)). If you print out `path1` and then *copy* this string and then interactively try to open and display the image with the *pasted* string using the PIL, does this work?

Comment: Hi! I don't understand your comment about prove it? The script gives error that "PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=P size=980x93 at 0xF185A8" does not exists from image.open(). Yes, sorry about the code after label1. I am not sure what you mean about the last part, you mean hardcode the path?

Comment: @user1610593 Yes, it's a way to trouble-shoot your problem. Display the generaetd path for the image, *copy* it, and *paste* it into a command, as is, to open/display the file. (You are copy/pasting so as to have the *exact* string being generated) - also, there are no other files other than image files in that directory right?

Comment: The error message indicates that `open` is not actually receiving a string. I don't believe the code shown here is what's actually generating that message.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your issue is with `image.open()`, I believe the problem is that you are treating the directory and file name as strings when you join them together:

```
path1 = dir + img1
```

Instead you should try using the `os.path` module to combine the two:

```
path1 = os.path.join(dir, img1)
```

Comment: While using `os.path.join()` is good practice over string ops in general, I don't think it makes a difference here

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. Yes, its image.open() that is the problem. I need it to use the dir/ + the random selected file (eg. an image) but image.open gets properties of the image for some reason instead of the path. I already tried os.path.join but no difference there =/